# Duplicate Help/Chat buttons with Avada theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, hubspot

[Overlapping Help/Chat buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBucC.png)

I'm using the Avada child them in Wordpress and I somehow ended up with overlapping Help/Chat buttons. I know one is connected to Hubspot the the other existed before I took over managing the website and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. OR which one would be better to keep.

I want just one accessible chat for the site. I don't want to reset the hubspot plugin until I've figured out which is which and what is better.

Comment: fix them with css ?